# What causes TcpListener Socket Error 10013?

Tags: .net, sockets, windows-7, tcplistener

I get error 10013. msdn says its a permission denied error.

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions
```

My app ran fine. I then made a code change and restarted it. I got that error. I suspected i have to reuse ports so i wrote this in and still had no luck

```
server.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
```

How do i solve this error?

-edit-

I did notice if i close FireFox (with its many tabs) and run the program it works...
Maybe it has something to do with a connection? (i had ajax communicate with it). I wonder what did it.

Comment: Perhaps firefox was using the port that your app was trying to grab.

Answer (score 10):

This error code is caused by attempting to `bind` to a port that is exclusively in use by another process. The most common cause is accidentally starting the same service twice.

If in doubt, a quick check of <strike>`netstat -a`</strike> [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) should reveal which process has the port open.

Comment: I see the list of local/remote ips and ports (along with state) but i dont see any process name.

Comment: I still cant tell what is happening. It feels like my winform app still is binding the address but it shouldnt be. NOTE: half the time i hard kill it.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been TCPView, not netstat; answer has been updated. What port are you binding to?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution to Socket Error #10013 Access Denied on a Delphi app when running the executable was to "Run As Administrator". For those of you who normally run outside of local admin, this may be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that can yields this error (WCF used) is scenario where you have two endpoints defined on same server using different protocols (http & net.tcp for example) but same port, something like this:

```
<service name="yourService">
<endpoint address="http://localhost:2112/ys" binding="basicHttpBinding" name="basicHttpEndPoint"
  contract="zza.Services.IzzaService" />
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:**2112**/" binding="netTcpBinding"
  name="netTcpEndPoint" contract="IyourService" />
<host>
  <baseAddresses>
    <add baseAddress="http://localhost:**2112**" />
  </baseAddresses>
</host>
```